# MongoDB: findOne returns null but sub document exists in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am adding custom list in db. After Calling a random custom list, the custom list created with sub document list in db. But it's showing it's sub document in console is null. My code ->

My Sub document Scheme->

```
const toSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name:{ type:String,required:true}
});
```

My main custom list Schema->

```
const newSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  sch:[toSchema]
});
const Work=mongoose.model("work",newSchema);
```

Now, I adding the collections & show it to console->

```
app.get("/post/:get",function(req,res){
  var ch=req.params.get;
  const item=new Todo({
    name:ch
  }); 
  const work=new Work({
    name:ch,
    sch:item
  });
  work.save();
  Work.findOne({name:ch},function(err,works){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log(works);
     }
 
});  
});
```

I am typing a custom list "home" & it's created successfully in
db. But the sub document showing null.

[image: Console output which was showing the null value instead of the sub document]

[image: Here the sub document created which was shown in mongoDB]

Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows `null` because `.save()` is asynchronous in nature, so you need to wait for it's execution to complete before trying to `find`, but if you just want to `find` the document you are saving, then you don't need to use `find` as `.save()` returns the document you are `saving`

```
 work.save(function(err, document) {
    if (err)
      console.error(err);
    else
      console.log(document);

  });
```

But if you are planning to use `.find()` you need to wait for `.save()` execution to finish

Answer (score 0):

It is showing null because in your Schema you declared `sch` as a array and trying to store object in it.

```
  const newSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  sch:[toSchema] // Declared Array

});
const Work=mongoose.model("work",newSchema);
```

That is why it is null.
If you want store object in it (In your case `const item`) then you need to declare `sch` as a object. Change your `newSchema` as mentioned below

```
const newSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  sch:{toSchema}
});
const Work=mongoose.model("work",newSchema);
```

Then it works.

Comment: Yes, Now I have address my problem. I have take a "insertMany" method instead of "save" & then in "insertMany" method I have added "find" method in else part of "insertMany" method.   Thanks, for help me.